# Longest Common Substring Algorithm for n strings

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following algorithm to find the longest common sub-string between two strings, I'd like to modify it such that it can take n number of strings. I'm not sure how many strings this function would take at a maximum but the upper limit is probably around 4-6.

Here's my base algorithm.

```
def lcs(s1, s2):
    m = [[0] * (1 + len(s2)) for i in xrange(1 + len(s1))]
    longest, x_longest = 0, 0
    for x in xrange(1, 1 + len(s1)):
        for y in xrange(1, 1 + len(s2)):
            if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
                m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
                if m[x][y] > longest:
                    longest = m[x][y]
                    x_longest = x
            else:
                m[x][y] = 0
    return s1[x_longest - longest: x_longest]
```

Answer (score 0):

If s1 and s2 are your strings, replace it with:

```
def lcs(*s):
...
```

Now you can call lcs(s1, s2, s3, s4)

and inside the function, s will be a tuple with the elements you passed, in this case it would be a tuple of 4 strings. You can also just pass a list of strings to the function and forget about *args.

Comment: What about accessing the variables for s3 and s4? I'm not sure how to refactor this code to work the way I'd like

Comment: @FelipeRios - `s3, s4 = s[2], s[3]`. You just index the tuple like a regular list

Comment: The number of nested for loops would depend on the number of parameters, so for an arbitrary number of strings you would have to do it recursively.